# Canvas clipTo method restoring the cleared area

Tags: jquery, html, fabricjs

I want to clip an image on the canvas based on an svg path where the image is dropped.
see the page i am doing here, http://qa.newagesme.com/wyz_editor/clip.php

here i can drag and drop an image from the left side on to the canvas, and it actually clips the canvas based on the path, but all the other parts of the canvas are not visible now, I don't want to happen this, other area should be visible too and image should be masked inside the path where it is dropped,
some part of the code is given below,

```
jQuery('#editor').droppable({accept: ".ui-draggable",drop: function( event, ui ) {
           topmost = undefined;
        var canvasContainer = jQuery("#editor"),
        canvasX = event.pageX - canvasContainer.offset().left,
        canvasY = event.pageY - canvasContainer.offset().top;
        canvasX = canvasX < 0 ? 0 : canvasX;
        canvasY = canvasY < 0 ? 0 : canvasY; 
        // alert(canvasX+'px'+canvasY+'px');
        var position = new Object({'x': canvasX, 'y': canvasY});
    jQuery.each(objs,function(index,val){

        if( val.containsPoint(position) && !(editor.isTargetTransparent(val, canvasX, canvasY)) ){ // checking if the image dropped on the path visible area
             topmost = val;  //to get the top most item only
        }


});
    if(topmost != undefined){
        var Img1 = new Image();
            Img1.onload = function (img) {
                //var attr = proportionalHeight(val,this);
                var Image1 = new fabric.Image(Img1, {
                    height: 150,
                    width:150,
                    left: canvasX,
                    lockUniScaling:true,
                    minScaleLimit:.3,
                    top: canvasY,
                    clipName: topmost.get("clipFor"),
                    scaleX: 0.7,
                    scaleY: 0.7,

                });
                var cont = editor.getContext("2d");
                cont.save();
                editor.clipTo=function(ctx){
                            //ctx.save();
                            topmost.render(ctx);
                           ctx.clip();

                            //return _.bind(clipByName, Image1)(ctx) 
                }
                cont.restore();
                editor.add(Image1); 


                 editor.renderAll();


            };  

                Img1.src = 'http://192.168.1.254/robin/wyz_editor/'+ui.draggable.find('img').attr('src');


    }
```

if you look at the link i provided above you will see the image is clipping correctly but all other items on the canvas is also getting clipped off.